# How to configure steak with akephalos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration-testing, akephalos

Some time ago I have tried to use the thoughtbot version of akephalos
based on this article http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/1658763359/thoughtbot-and-the-holy-grail, but could not make it work, does anyone have a sample app to show me
how to test with steak, capybara, akephalos. If not is there any app sample with Steak and selenium.
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

I have written an small app based on the configuration I copied from a rspec test
https://github.com/boriscy/akephalos_steak